# Regex select anything but numbers containing 5

Tags: php, regex

I need to exclude all numbers that contain 5 from a string using regex.

Given a string of integers separated by <del>commas</del> spaces `i.e. "1 2 3 4 5 ... 15 16"` i need to return this string with excluded numbers that contain `5 (5, 15, 54 etc.)` using regex. I tried to achieve this by using negative lookahed with no luck. It successfully captures numbers which end with `5 (15, 75)` but not the ones which start with it `(56,57)`.
Please help me figure out what i am missing.

```
$s = implode(' ', range($start, $end));
$sm = preg_replace('/(?!\d*5\d*)(\d+)\d*/', '', $s)
```

Comment: You say "Given a string of integers separated by commas " but you separate them by space.

Comment: You are right, pasted the wrong one, but does it actually matter?
Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to select a number that contains a `5` (optionally remove space after that too) within it and replace it with empty string,

```
-?\d*5\d* ?
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cFGzqd/3)**

Hence try changing your code to,

```
$s = "1 2 3 4 -5 8 7 15 7 22 51 15 16 -23532 215 232 522 952 332 -25 56 434";
$sm = preg_replace('/-?\d*5\d* ?/', '', $s);
echo $sm;
```

Prints,

```
1 2 3 4 8 7 7 22 16 232 332 434
```

Comment: What do the word boundaries do?

Comment: Word boundaries ensure, your number matches as a whole number although in your case, since your numbers are already space separated, you can remove them.

Comment: @user3783243: Removed word boundaries as they aren't needed in your case

Comment: It seems your sample does not consider negative numbers, does it?

Comment: Just have to prepend `-?` in the beginning of regex. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around why you don't need the word boundaries here. Can you expand on this? Since `-?` and `d*` and ` *` can all match nothing then why do we not get matches of all solitary 5s even in hte middle of numbers?

Comment: @JackPRead: Word boundaries are needed when you do not want the intended match to have a partial match in a larger text. For e.g. in text `aaa1212aaa` if we just want to match pure numbers and not numbers surrounded by some letters, then we need to write `\b\d+\b` due to which this regex will not find a match in `aaa1212aaa` and will only match if number is surrounded by characters which are not part of word and hence starting number and ending number will have a word boundary. and match `\b\d+\b` regex. So we can have word boundary at the end of my regex although it will be redundant.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thanks for reply. Yes, I understand that. I just realised now in typing this why I was getting confused. It is quite silly but I was thinking about your regex as a lazy regex and therefore matching as little as possible and therefore matching just `5`. Of course I'm just wrong, not sure why I thought this. Brain doing stupid things.

Comment: @JackPRead: Yes brother, I agree this happens at times. May be because of some stress build up or may be when something else is bothering our brain and we can't precisely focus, despite knowing it quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Use this pattern

`\b(?:[0-4]|[6-9])+\b`

It is quite simple. `\b` is a word boundary (this is short for `(?:\w\W|\W\w)`) and then it searches for digits 0-4 or 6-9.

Further explanation:
`\b` word boundary
`(?:` start non-capturing group
`[0-4]|[6-9]` match a character between 0-4 or 6-9 inclusively. i.e. any digit except 5
`)` end capture group
`+` quantier to give 1 or more of the previous match which is the capture group
`\b` word boundary

edit: changed * to + as I can't imagine a reason why you'd want to match no digits

Comment: After thinking further on it overnight I realised this can be further simplified to just `\b[0-46-9]+\b`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = '1 2 3 6 5 55 12 14 75 61 8590';


$data = explode(' ',$string);


foreach($data as $row){
    if (strpos($row, '5') !== false) {
        $newArray[] = $row;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

Above code will accept a string seperated by coma, and after explode will put each of the values that contain '5' in a new array to be printed. Output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 55
    [2] => 75
    [3] => 8590
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to do this with regex only.